# How to SUM column values from multiple rows with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, mariadb

I have a table in MySQL that lists stock purchases of a user (so there are multiple rows of the same stock with different prices and quantities).

I'd like to know how I can list the unique stocks with just the sum of all the stocks and total amount spent on that stock.

So for example, here's the original table,

```
+------------+--------+-----------+
| ticker     | shares | price     |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| AMARAJABAT |      5 |  720.0000 |
| AMARAJABAT |      5 |  732.0000 |
| ENDURANCE  |      2 | 1650.0000 |
| ENDURANCE  |      2 | 1750.0000 |
| EXIDEIND   |     21 |  163.5000 |
| EXIDEIND   |     21 |  172.1000 |
+------------+--------+-----------+
```

and a select of the table to get the shares*price,

`SELECT ticker,shares,price,shares*price AS spent FROM bought ORDER BY ticker;`

```
+------------+--------+-----------+------------+
| ticker     | shares | price     | spent      |
+------------+--------+-----------+------------+
| AMARAJABAT |      5 |  720.0000 |  3600.0000 |
| AMARAJABAT |      5 |  732.0000 |  3660.0000 |
| ENDURANCE  |      2 | 1650.0000 |  3300.0000 |
| ENDURANCE  |      2 | 1750.0000 |  3500.0000 |
| EXIDEIND   |     21 |  163.5000 |  3433.5000 |
| EXIDEIND   |     21 |  172.1000 |  3614.1000 |
+------------+--------+-----------+------------+
```

And I'd like to actually sum the values of the shares columns (for the same stock) and the amount spent on each. i.e an output of,

```
+------------+-------------+------------+
| ticker     | SUM(shares) | SUM(spent) |
+------------+-------------+------------+
| AMARAJABAT |          10 |  7260.0000 |
| ENDURANCE  |           4 |  6800.0000 |
| EXIDEIND   |          42 |  7047.6000 |
+------------+-------------+------------+
```

but can't seem to figure out how I can sum multiple columns and rows by `ticker`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `GROUP BY ticker`?

Comment: doesn't work :( (only shows the shares and price of last row that matches for each ticker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum `shares` and `shares` * `price` and group by `ticker`.

```
SELECT ticker, SUM(shares) AS 'Total Shares', SUM(shares * price) AS `Total Spent`
FROM bought
GROUP BY ticker
ORDER BY ticker;
```

Answer (score 2):

just group by :

```
select ticker , sum(shares), sum(spent)
from bought
group by ticker
order by ticker;
```